# Angular: form control value and form value not the same

Tags: angular

When using the `valueChanges` callback in Angular I noticed the values `form.get('field').value` and `form.value.field` are not the same.

Example:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  email: ['default@example.com'],
)}

this.form.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(this.form.get('email').value);
  console.log(this.form.value.email);
});
```

On the first change `this.form.get('email').value` will equal value of `value` (= the updated value). But `this.form.value.email` will still equal `default@example.com`.

- Is this expected behavior?
- Should I always use `this.form.get('email').value` over `this.form.value.email`?

You may also try out the stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-jrvley?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: good question, just as a note if you subscribe to form.valueChanges values are the same all the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're logging from within the form control changes, and the form group probably hasn't been updated yet.

If you log the form group value from within the form group value changes observable, you see matching results.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-fg8hws

I changed

```
this.contactForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(`VALUE: ${value}`);
  console.log(`FORM CONTROL VALUE: ${this.contactForm.get('email').value}`);
  console.log(`FORM VALUE: ${this.contactForm.value.email}`);
})
```

to

```
this.contactForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(`VALUE: ${value}`);
  console.log(`FORM CONTROL VALUE: ${this.contactForm.get('email').value}`);      
})

this.contactForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(`FORM VALUE: ${this.contactForm.value.email}`);
})
```

Edit:

And to answer your other question, I always use the `this.form.get('name')` syntax. Mainly for compatibility with dynamically built forms.